# NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Hey guys am new to flutter and i have been having this issue of displaying data to screen.
my error

```
NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null
```

my code

```
class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  var user;
  Future getUserDT() async {
    Map data = await getStored_user('login');
    setState(() {
      user = data;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserDT();
  }
```

where i get the error

```
              Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "${user['user']['user_name']}" //this is where i get the error,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 24,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: kBlueColor,
                            fontFamily: kQuicksand,
                          ),
                        ),
```

trying to display user info to the screen

Comment: `user` or `user['user']` is null and that's why you are facing this issue. You've to handle null cases for this.

Answer (score 1):

In your `getUserDT()` until the `getStored_user()` method is not done, `setState()` function doesn't get called. So when the `build()` function runs and if the `setState()` method is still not called you get this error.

```dart
  Future getUserDT() async {
    Map data = await getStored_user('login');
    
    //THIS DOESN'T GET CALLED UNTIL getStored_user() is done
    setState(() {
      user = data;
    });
  }
```

Because you are using `Future`, you should use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html). And don't call `getUserDT()` in `initState()` anymore.

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: getUserDT,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) =>
      snapshot.hasData ? Text('user') : Text('Loading'),
),
```

Comment: Thanks alot it worked for me i just modified the snapshot.hasData to user != null and it worked fine. tanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Based on your initState(), flutter first calls build() method, then getUserDT() (which then calls another time the build() method).

You are getting the error because user is null the first time build method is called.

You should use a `FutureBuilder`:

```
   FutureBuilder(
    future: getUserDT(),
    builder: (context, snap) {
      if (snap.hasData) {
        var user = snap.data!;
        return Column(
         children: [
          Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 0),
           child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
             Text(
              "${user['user']['user_name']}"
              style: TextStyle(
               fontSize: 24,
               fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
               color: kBlueColor,
               fontFamily: kQuicksand,
              ),
             ),
            ],
           ),
          ),
         ],
        );
      } else if (snap.hasError) {
        return Container();
      } else {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.blue));
      }
    });
```

---

WRONG ANSWER (NOT TO BE USED):

Change `initState()`

```
@override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      getUserDT();
    });
    super.initState();
    
  }
```

Comment: This will still throw an error as `user` will be null for the very first time until the API call is finished.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I just update my answer